# How to keep track of last user activity using hooks?

Tags: php, yii

Using Yii MVC, I want to know when a user is still on my webpage, so I need to store the last time a user has been active.

Is there a hook that can update a timestamp field in the user table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, adding the following code in the components/Controller.php

The code, uses the `afterAction` hook, so everytime a action happens, the update is triggered.

```
    public function keepAlive() {
        if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
            User::model()->updateByPk(
                    Yii::app()->user->id, array('lastactive' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) //CURRENT_TIMESTAMP..this working fine
            );
        }
    }

// Runs after any action in controller
    public function afterAction($action) {
        self::keepAlive();
        parent::afterAction($action);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do it yourself with javascript help.
Put on every page javascript interval function that sends (ajax) request to your specific action and update user timestamp.

So to sumup: 
Javascript on page load: `ajaxUpdateActivity( userId );`
Yii action understands your request and update what needs to be updated `actionAjaxUpdateActivity()`

Comment: yes, true, you can do this using js also, but i found the right answer, using hooks

Comment: ok, thats cool. Yes, you don't need js if it's ok to not track user while he is looking on page long time. If he is on page for 10min (wow, long time!) you get activity set 10min in the past. If you willing in the future to add also user activity updating while he reading long post you will need js.

Comment: if you want to refresh the timer, from 5 to 5 minutes, you should use js, if not, use the hooks